# Webdriver - Automation of EXT 3.4 application - How to convert the EXT 3.4 table in to List<map<key,value>>

Tags: extjs, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am automating the website which is using EXT 3.4 as front end.

I am dealing with a table grid, in which every row itself is a table.

As I have Id's generated dynamically, I am resorting to CSS locator

I need the answer of following:

1) How to traverse through the child elements once you get first element.
2) Any way to make generic function to which accepts the header id and returns the data
3) Any component query/query of EXT 3.4 which can help me in this.

Thanks much for helping

Answer (score 1):

**Q1: How to traverse through the child elements once you get first element ?**

In ExtJS 3.4 you need to put id for each element and then for fetching the element you have get hold of the id by using below code.

`Ext.getCmp('ChildElementId');`

And then you go ahead with your task.

**Q2: Any way to make generic function to which accepts the header id and returns the data ?**

Yes, This you can achive by multiple ways. I usually prefere to write in one seperate js you can say some util class or something. This entierly depend on the requirement. (Which is not clear in your question) [Please see the link for better understanding.](https://www.sencha.com/blog/top-10-ext-js-development-practices-to-avoid-2/)

**Q3: Any component query/query of EXT 3.4 which can help me in this**.

Ext.ComponentQuery is introduced from 4.0 so you can not use in your application but you can achive this by using id which I explain earilear.

Comment: Thanks UDID..To tell you more  about the use case, I have EXT JS 3.4 data grid, which seems like a table but it is a collection of tables. I dont have non-dynamic ID for for child nodes/parent node. I just have class name which I need to customize. I have tried EXT.getcmp but it says "undefined result" for Class name instead of ID. Ideally I want to iterate through the whole grid(as the table is dynamically generated with all rows as tables) and get the data and convert the data in List<map<key,value>> where key is header and value is data for header. Again thanks